# Send multiple emails with different deferred delivery times to one email address

Tags: excel, vba, email

I want to send email with deferred delivery according to the cells ("A2:A4").

For instance, if today is 2 February 2023, send three emails for delivery on 6 February, 13 February and 20 February.

The VBA code sends an email for last cell ("A4").

For ("A2") AND ("A3") the email won't be created.

```vb
Sub Send_Deferred_Mail_From_Excel()
Dim OutlookApp As Object
Dim OutlookMail As Object

Dim xRg As Range
Set xRg = Range("A2:A4")
Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutlookMail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)

'Send Email Using Excel VBA Macro Code
With OutlookMail
    .To = "email"
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "HI"
    .Body = "HELLO"

    'Send email on specific day & time
    .DeferredDeliveryTime = Range("A2") + Range("A3") + Range("A4")
    .Display 'or just put .Send to directly send the mail instead of display
End With

Set OutlookMail = Nothing
Set OutlookApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got how to send multiple emails to one email address using date & time in cells

```
Sub Send_Deferred_Mail_From_Excel()
Dim i As Integer, OutlookMail As Object, lr As Long
Dim xRg As Range, Bk As Range

' get last row 
lr = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
' create range from row 2 to last row
Set xRg = Range("A2:A" & lr)
Set OutlookMail = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

For Each Bk In xRg
With OutlookMail.CreateItem(0)
.To = "email@gmail.com"
.CC = ""
.subject = "HI"
.Body = "HELLO"

' Send email on specific day & time
.DeferredDeliveryTime = Bk.Value
.Display
End With
Next Bk
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Please try it like this.

Make a list in Sheets("Sheet1") with :

```
In column A : Names of the people
In column B : E-mail addresses
In column C:Z : Filenames like this C:\Data\Book2.xls (don't have to be Excel files)
```

The Macro will loop through each row in "Sheet1" and if there is a E-mail address in column B
and file name(s) in column C:Z it will create a mail with this information and send it.

```
Sub Send_Files()
'Working in Excel 2000-2016
'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim FileCell As Range
    Dim rng As Range

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    For Each cell In sh.Columns("B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

        'Enter the path/file names in the C:Z column in each row
        Set rng = sh.Cells(cell.Row, 1).Range("C1:Z1")

        If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
           Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) > 0 Then
            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

            With OutMail
                .to = cell.Value
                .Subject = "Testfile"
                .Body = "Hi " & cell.Offset(0, -1).Value

                For Each FileCell In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
                    If Trim(FileCell) <> "" Then
                        If Dir(FileCell.Value) <> "" Then
                            .Attachments.Add FileCell.Value
                        End If
                    End If
                Next FileCell

                .Send  'Or use .Display
            End With

            Set OutMail = Nothing
        End If
    Next cell

    Set OutApp = Nothing
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Send_Deferred_Mail_From_Excel()
Dim OutlookApp As Object
Dim OutlookMail As Object

Dim xRg As Range
Set xRg = Range("A2:A4")
Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutlookMail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)

'Send Email Using Excel VBA Macro Code
With OutlookMail
.To = "email"
.CC = ""
.BCC = ""
.Subject = "HI"
.Body = "HELLO"

''Try in a loop instead.
for each cell in xRg
    'Send email on specific day & time
    .DeferredDeliveryTime = cell
    .Display 'or just put .Send to directly send the mail instead of display
next cell

End With
Set OutlookMail = Nothing
Set OutlookApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Expand the For loop to include `Set OutlookMail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)`.